# TestNG - Test/Suite scoped variable accessible for single-class / method execution

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, functional-testing

I'm trying to allow parameters specified via testng.xml suite-wide or test-wide to be accessible for single-test execution. e.g.

in testng.xml

```
<suite name="All">
    <test name="test1">
        <parameter name="test-wide-param" value="sharedvalue"/>
        <packages>
            <package name=".*">
                <include name=".*" />
            </package>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

in test class:

```
@Parameter("test-wide-param")
@BeforeTest
public void globalSetUp(String sharedInfo){
    value = sharedInfo;
}

@Test
public void test(){
    //use value
}
```

It works very well when I execute the entire test suite, but fails when I try to run single test class / method. What is the correct way of implementing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. When you execute a single test class or method, you are not using your XML configuration. Eclipse is generating the suite on the fly. If you want to use something similar, I would suggest a java properties file. If you are using spring or maven, both have very nice support for properties files. If you are not there are many ways to fairly easily implement it yourself.

Comment: There are global parameters overwritten at test suite level, which is nice. Guess we'll have to use property files and configure them specifically for each test suite then. Sad news :(